# bootstrap inline input and button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how create this login form on bootstrap 3.0

http://joxi.ru/zcBBUtg5CbB8ELTo5CA

My code:

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline">
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Адрес электронной почты">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Пароль">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Войти</button>
     </div>

</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mborodov/Ls684/

But, i need padding between inputs and inline password input and submit button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Ls684/2/

```
<form role="form" class="padding-15 black round-5 form-inline">
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Адрес электронной почты">
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Пароль">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Войти</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.form-control[type="email"]{
    width : 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-control[type="password"]{
    width : 60%;
    float : left;
}

button{
    width : 30%;
    float : left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Thx, but this layout not responsive. I need column width layout for all devices

Comment: thx, but how make send button fix size and password input resonsive in %

Comment: To have a responsive form, you must modify my css with pourcentage. jsfiddle.net/Ls684/2

Comment: Ok, i change minimal you code http://jsfiddle.net/mborodov/Ls684/3/. This is work example.

Comment: Glad to have helped you.